# Add incrementally row values of a column of type string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following values

```
 UserID   ParentID  Levels  Path
   1        NULL      0     A1
   5        1         1     A2
   9        5         2     A3
   43       9         3     A4
```

The output should be like followed :

```
 UserID   ParentID  Levels  FinalPath
   1        NULL      0     A1/
   5        1         1     A1/A2/
   9        5         2     A1/A2/A3/
   43       9         3     A1/A2/A3/A4/
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Comment: What have you tried already, can you add your attempt to the question please? My first thought for these kinds of things are [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server) or [recursive common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions). Have you already looked at those?

Comment: duplicate, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489281/sql-server-recursive-query-to-show-path-of-parents/63489762

Comment: @MLeblanc, Thanks for pointing out. I did not come across the question so posted it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using a recusive common table expression.

**Sample data**

```
create table users
(
  userid int,
  parentid int,
  levels int,
  path nvarchar(100)
);

insert into users (userid, parentid, levels, path) values
(1,  NULL, 0, 'A1'),
(5,  1,    1, 'A2'),
(9,  5,    2, 'A3'),
(43, 9,    3, 'A4');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select u.userid, u.parentid, u.levels, u.path
  from users u
  where u.parentid is null
    union all
  select u.userid, u.parentid, u.levels, convert(nvarchar(100), c.path + '/' + u.path)
  from users u
  join cte c
    on c.userid = u.parentid
)
select c.userid, c.parentid, c.levels, c.path + '/' as FinalPath
from cte c;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64f891bc365e15dd9b95bb9e60153021)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed query. Meanwhile I tried using recursive CTE and was able to solve. Still thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that both calculates the Level and appends the Path.

Data

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_table;
go
create table dbo.test_table(
  UserID          int,
  ParentID         int,
  [Path]            varchar(5));
                    
insert dbo.test_table([UserID], [ParentID], [Path]) values
(1,null, 'A1'),
(5,1, 'A2'),
(9,5, 'A3'),
(43,9, 'A4');
```

Query

```
;with recur_cte([UserId], [ParentID], h_level, [Path]) as (
    select [UserId], [ParentID], 0, cast([Path] as varchar(100))
    from dbo.test_table
    where [ParentID] is null
    union all
    select tt.[UserId], tt.[ParentID], rc.h_level+1, cast(concat(tt.[Path], '/', rc.[Path]) as varchar(100)) 
    from dbo.test_table tt join recur_cte rc on tt.[ParentID]=rc.[UserId])
select * from recur_cte;
```

Results

```
UserId  ParentID    h_level Path
1       NULL        0       A1
5       1           1       A1/A2
9       5           2       A1/A2/A3
43      9           3       A1/A2/A3/A4
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed query. I tried using recursive CTE and was able to solve. Thank you for your effort..